# What is the format of HTTP 1.1 header values?

Tags: http, http-headers, rfc, http-protocols, abnf

I read the rfc7230 section 3.2. After removing obsolete rules, the spec about header field is:

```
header-field   = field-name ":" OWS field-value OWS
field-name     = token
field-value    = *field-content
field-content  = field-vchar [ 1*( SP / HTAB ) field-vchar ]
field-vchar    = VCHAR
VCHAR          = %x21-7E; visible (printing) characters
```

I am confused by the definition of `field-content`. It seems that it matches 1 or 2 `VCHAR`s, with any amount of space in between, but it will not match another space after a `field-content` match.

For example, for `name:a<sp>b<sp>c`, `field-name` will match `name`, but `field-content` will match `a<sp>b` and then the next `<sp>` cannot be matched by another `field-content`, thus this header is invalid.

However, `name:a<sp>bc<sp>d` is valid because there are two matches for `field-content`, `a<sp>b` and `c<sp>d`.

I think this is inconsistent. Is this intended or do I misunderstood something?

Comment: @RemyLebeau multiple `field-content`s cannot be separated by spaces. `field-value = *field-content`, there is no space.

Comment: Sounds like an issue that should be taken up with [IETF's HTTP Working Group](http://httpwg.org), who actual defines the HTTP protocol specs.

Comment: This might be the same issue as the one described here: <https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid4189>

Comment: @JulianReschke Yes, that is the problem I described.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but :

The updated [RFC 9110 Section 5.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-field-values) still holds this ambiguity.
Therefore, i would suggest sticking to the explaination described [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid4189).